# findgameojectswithtag list taking duplicates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Making a fisher-yates card shuffler in unity c#, the cards are compiled on a list with CardObjects=GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cards") and shuffled by the thing but the findgameobjects thing always "finds" duplicates of a gameobject with the tag, for example elemnt23 of the list might be a 10 of clubs but then element17 and element41 are also 10 of clubs, these duplicates fill up space on the list meaning that the list runs out of room for the other cards, meaning there are a few cards just lying around not doing anything and not on the list. Everything is working with no bugs the only problem is that it just finds the same object more then once.

code (triggered by a button if that means anything):

```
public void Shuffler()
{
    CardObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cards");
    for (int positionOfArray = 0; positionOfArray < CardObjects.Length; positionOfArray++)
    {
        GameObject obj = CardObjects[positionOfArray];
        int randomizeArray = Random.Range(0, positionOfArray);
        CardObjects[randomizeArray] = obj;
    }
```

}

also using this line to move the cards around into place (locationator1 is an invisible gameobject that the card in the element0 place on the list goes to, idk if this is relevant).

```
CardObjects[0].transform.position = new Vector3(Locationator1.position.x, Locationator1.position.y, Locationator1.position.z);
```

[list with a few 9's duped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJs8z.png)

[what it looks like shuffled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMks8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindGameObjectsWithTag` works perfectly, it's the wrong shuffling logic that's the culprit.

From Wikipedia ([Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)):

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from 0 to n−1 do
     j ← random integer such that i ≤ j < n
     exchange a[i] and a[j]
```

Based on the above:

1. You need to *exchange* objects, but your code is just replacing one with another, effectively duplicating the reference of the first one to the new place and throwing the second one away. This is direct cause of your duplicated objects issue.
2. As you are going from the lowest index, your min range for the random number (`j`) should be `positionOnArray` (`i`), and max should be `CardObjects.Length` (`n`). Also, we can iterate the loop until `n - 1` instead of `n`, as otherwise we get a redundant last iteration which "shuffles" the object with itself.

Thus, this will work as intended:

```
for (int positionOfArray = 0; positionOfArray < CardObjects.Length - 1; positionOfArray++)
{
    GameObject obj = CardObjects[positionOfArray];
    int randomizeArray = Random.Range(positionOfArray, CardObjects.Length);
    CardObjects[positionOfArray] = CardObjects[randomizeArray];
    CardObjects[randomizeArray] = obj;
}
```